# НЕ получается получить объект с Firebase на Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase

Помогите решить проблему, использую БД Firebase. Есть объкет, он достаточно сложный и состоит из других объектов. Так же есть функция для отправки этого объекта:

```
fun sendScheduleToFirebase(schedule: Shedule) {
        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        val reference = database.getReference("schedule")

        reference.child("sheduleID").setValue(schedule)
}
```

С этим проблем нет, в БД все отправляется, но получить этот объект не получается, приложение просто вылетает. Функция для получения объекта:

```
fun getScheduleFromFirebase(scheduleId: String, callback: (Shedule?) -> Unit) {
        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        val reference = database.getReference("schedule")

        reference.child(scheduleId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val schedule = dataSnapshot.getValue(Shedule::class.java)
                callback(schedule)
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                callback(null)
            }
        })
}
```

Пример вызова этой функции:

```
getScheduleFromFirebase("sheduleID") { schedule ->
            if (schedule != null) {
                val textView : TextView = findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle)
                textView.text = shedule!!.a11.teacher
            }
}
```

Причем с простыми типами как String все работает хорошо и нет никаких проблем

Comment: Было бы неплохо увидеть какая ошибка вылетает в логах, после которой крашится приложение